# Two Checkbox in one row react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using the react-table package, with a single checkbox it working fine, but I need to have two checkboxes in a single row so if I do click on one checkbox the other checkbox should not be checked. I am facing an issue with react table API that if I click on one checkbox others also get checked.

here is my stackblitz line

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6brptb

Comment: On the `<input>` tag on line 78, delete `{...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()}` and you'll see that the checkboxes are now independent.  Beyond that, it's not clear what you want to happen.

Comment: Thanks, yes, so when i do click on header checkbox it would checked all, but from row if m unchecking the one checkbox the header should unchecked